# how to center align IMG in div?

Tags: html, css

How to center align IMG in div?

```
<div id="head">
  <div id="panel">
    <img/>
    <a href="#"><img/></a>
    <a href="#"><img/></a>
    <a href="#"><img/></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Img have different Width and Height.

css:

```
#head{
    float:right;
    margin:15px 100px 30px 30px;
    text-align:center;
    height:20px;
    width:160px;
}
#panel img{
    margin-left:10px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: your css seems to work as-is. do you want the images to center align vertically + horizontally?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

May be this is what you're looking for:

```
#panel img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

## [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/H8MEj/)

Answer (score 1):

Set the width of the "#panel" div so there is room for it to be centered.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give `#panel` a width before the image will center.

Answer (score -1):

Give the `<div id="panel" align="center">`. Images will come in center

Comment: `align` is deprecated, don't use it.